# Adding new efi variables to the efivarfs filesystem in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, uefi

I want to add a new efivar in /sys/firmware/efi/vars/ which will hold the binary content of ACPI overlay file as explained [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/acpi/ssdt-overlays.txt), under *"Loading ACPI SSDTs from EFI variables"*

I am able to create new var using `dd` command, but it gets wiped out on reboot.

How can I add new efivars in a persistent way. In the kernel [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-firmware-efi-vars), I can see that there is a `new_var` binary in `/sys/firmware/efi/vars/`, however that needs `struct efi_variable`, but what I want is to create an efivar/file in /sys/firmware/efi/vars which holds my binary AML file.

Any help please?

Comment: It may be worth verifying your system is actually able to persistently store UEFI variables, or changes to UEFI variables. This is not possible on for example certain embedded ARM platforms.

Comment: Take a look at here: https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2012/12/efivars-and-efivarfs.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [efivar](https://github.com/rhboot/efivar) library for this type of operation. This way you don't need to worry about whether your system is using efivarfs or the deprecated efivars interface, and also don't need to manually handle the accidental variable removal mitigations.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable info. However, this could have been a comment, rather than an answer. However, your last sentence makes some sense. Maybe I was doing correct but the storage is not persistent as you pointed out. The board I am using is **Intel Joule 570x** .  I am booting the kernel from a USB device.

Comment: @InsaneCoder Good point. Answer edited to move the bit that really should have been a comment into a comment on the question. I still prefer to keep the "use efivar" as an answer, since I don't think we have that bit in any existing answers on SO.